# send a response to end-user based on otp verification in WSO2 enterprise integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

I have created a module for verifying the end-user via SMS and OTP. After the module verifies the end user, another API should be called automatically and the response sent to the end user. I have attached the flow.
[image]

How can I handle this procedure in WSO2 Integration studio ??

Answer (score 1):

There are so many unknowns in your description. But if I understand correctly you have an endpoint for OTP and an endpoint for some business process X and then the response should be sent to the end user.

This sounds like two call mediators, [endpoints](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/endpoint_examples/using-http-endpoints/), [endpoint error handling](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/use-cases/examples/endpoint_examples/endpoint-error-handling/), [service chaining](https://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-by-example-service-chaining/)/[service chaining](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/send-Mediator/#specifying-a-response-handling-sequence-service-chaining) and some unstated logic around failure scenarios using a combination of [switch mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/switch-Mediator/#switch-case-mediator) and [faultSequence](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/best-Practices/#behaviour-of-the-faultsequence) depending on situation encountered. You'll also want to understand the best practices around [Send vs Call mediators](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/best-Practices/#using-the-call-vs-callout-vs-send-mediators).

This [older document "Exposing Several Services as a Single Service"](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Exposing+Several+Services+as+a+Single+Service) I believe provides your answer, with the above concepts, of how you can achieve this type of functionality described.